# Converting Google sheets to Excel 2003 (.xls) using Apps Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

Currently, it seems Google has no way of converting Sheets to .xls format. So, I'm trying to use App Script to parse values from Sheet into a .XLS format. Here's the sample code below.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1...3f');
var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('17..f');
sourceFolder.createFile("Test File",sheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getDisplayValues(), MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY);
```

Data in Sheets has headers looks like this: [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZiMc.png)

However after converted to .xls, it looks like this all in cell A1: Name,Age,Fred,30,Jane,25

I've tried using:

```
Drive.Files.get(fileId).exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY]
```

But Google doesn't support it. Has to be MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you export your Google Sheet in a .XLSX file (which you can) and then convert that into XLS format in Excel instead? It would be way easier. In excel you can do that by going to *File->Save As->Save As Type (dropdown) -> Excel 97-2003 Workbook*

Comment: Hello Mateo, the purpose of the exercise is to create an Excel file to be uploaded into another application - without having to use Excel. Excel will eventually be installed on my machine.

Comment: Why do you need it to be in the 2003 version instead of the actualised xlsx formated version?

Comment: I have another application that consumes only .xls file. I already know how to create xlsx within Google, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

As of today, it is not doable in Google Sheets to export in `.xls` neither from the UI nor from Apps Script. If you would like to request this feature, you can do so by [posting a feature request in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features)

## Workaround

Use excel or other online tool for converting the `.xlsx` file to `.xls` or work with applications that work with the updated version of Microsoft excel.